# Сочетания клавиш W10

Tags: windows, клавиатура, музыка

Всем привет!
Какие сочетания клавиш использует клавиатура с мультимедиа кнопками?
Например таких клавиш как:

● вкл / выкл звук, 

● - / + громкость,

● << / >> переключение треков,

● Стоп,

● Плей / Пауза

Необходимо эмулировать нажатия этих клавиш.
P.S. Именно без стороннего ПО.

Comment: никакие не используют, у этих кнопок скан-коды другие

Comment: Благодарю за наводку! Кажется это то, что нужно. =)